# How to get some child nodes by id with all parents (DoctrineExtensions, Gedmo-Tree NestedTreeRepository, Symfony)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-extensions, gedmo-tree

**Goal:**

I have a category entity.
Every category can have subcategories.

Now I want to get specific category nodes by id with *all* its parents

**My current solution (custom repository function):**

```
public function getChildrenHierarchyByCategoryIDs($categoryIDsArray)
{
    $qb = $this->getNodesHierarchyQueryBuilder();
    $qb->andWhere('node.id in (:categoryIDs)')
       ->setParameter('categoryIDs', $categoryIDsArray)
        ->orWhere('node.id in (:rootNodes)') // "Workaround", get all available root nodes (1st level only) manually, because I don't know how to get them by children's parentID (node.parent) "automatically" (with second level etc.)
        ->setParameter('rootNodes', $this->getRootNodes())
    ;

    $aComponents = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    return $this->buildTreeArray($aComponents);
}
```

**Question:**

How can I get the parents (of all nodes found by id) automatically, instead of fetching every possible parent manually by id (See "Workaround" in code)?

I can't find any solution..

I think it should be something like: `->orWhere('node.id in (node.parent)')` which is not working. ([Syntax Error] line 0, col 89: Error: Expected Literal, got 'node')

Thanks in advance for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all parent nodes (in the hierarchy) of given node, it's rather simple:

- in your entity, i.e. Category, add the following convenient method:

```
public function getParentNodes(?Category $node = null, $parents = []): array
{
    if (!$node) {
        $node = $this;
    }
    if (null !== $this->getParent()) {
        $parent = $this->getParent();
        $parents[] = $parent;
        return $parent->getParentNodes($node, $parents);    
    }
    return $parents;
}
```

after this, the `$parents` array (and the metho calling result itself) will contain all parent nodes (objects) of the given node